# Mosaic dataset offers sensors unavailable in ortho mapping workspace

Tags: arcgis-pro, imagery, mosaic-dataset, orthorectification

I am trying to build an orthomosaic with PlanetScope data in ArcGIS Pro. Strangely, it appears that some sensors available under the mosaic workflow are not available for the Ortho Mapping Workspace. For example, PlanetScope products [are listed](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/satellite-sensor-raster-types.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_946A2AD0F0254B50ABB6DB91AF9110F6) as a supported sensor type in the [ortho mapping workspace satellite imagery workflow](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/create-an-ortho-mapping-workspace-from-satellite-imagery.htm). When creating a mosaic dataset, that platform is readily available :

[image: mosaic product list]

But in the ortho mapping workspace, no such option exists:

[image: ortho mapping workspace product list]

ArcGIS Pro indicates that you only need RPC's and a DEM for the satellite ortho mapping workflow. Theoretically, basic (no geometric correction) PS2 data with RPC's should be suitable for this. How can PlanetScope/PS2 imagery be brought into an ortho mapping workspace?